# Error: function must be payable but it does not contain transaction

Tags: arrays, mapping, error, payable

I'm new to blockchain and solidity. I've acquired a problem that seems strange to me. Look the code below

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Dealership {
    
    address owner;
    
    address [] dealerWallets;
    
    struct Type {
        address wallet;
        string category;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Type) dealerType;
    
    struct Product {
        string brand;
        string model;
        uint price;
        bool isSold;
    }
    
    mapping (address => mapping (uint => Product)) listOfDealerProduct;
    
    mapping (address => uint) countDealerProducts;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    } 
    
    // SET AND GET DEALER TYPE
    
    function setDealerType(string memory productType) public {
        dealerType[msg.sender] = Type(msg.sender, productType);
        dealerWallets.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getAllDealerByType() public view returns(Type [] memory) {
        Type [] memory newDealerType = new Type[](dealerWallets.length);
         
        for(uint i = 0; i < dealerWallets.length; i++) {
            newDealerType[i] = dealerType[dealerWallets[i]];
        }
        
        return newDealerType;
    }
    
    // SET AND GET DEALER LIST PRODUCT
    
    function setDealerListOfProduct(uint id, string memory brand,string memory model, uint price) public {
        listOfDealerProduct[msg.sender][id] = Product(brand, model, price, false);
        countDealerProducts[msg.sender] = id;
    }
    
    function getTotalProdcutsByDealer(address wallet) public view returns(uint) {
       return countDealerProducts[wallet];
    }
    
    
    function getAllProductsByDealer(address wallet) public view returns(Product[] memory) {
        Product [] memory newListProductByDealer = new Product[](countDealerProducts[wallet]);
        
        for(uint i = 0; i <= countDealerProducts[wallet]; i++) {
            newListProductByDealer[i] = listOfDealerProduct[wallet][i];
        }
        
        return newListProductByDealer;
    }
    
}
```

So i've got function getAllProductsByDealer which only returns the products stock that the dealership have. But somehow when i call it i always got an error like this.

```
call to Dealership.getAllProductsByDealer errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Could you show your client code where you call Dealership.getAllProductsByDealer ? Chances are you are sending a value to it given the error message, having the source would help to answer you more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one error. Arrays in solidity are zero based, so valid indexes for `newListProductByDealer` are `0` to `countDealerProducts[wallet]-1`.

The `for` exit condition should be `i < countDealerProducts[wallet]` and not `i <= countDealerProducts[wallet]`

```
function getAllProductsByDealer(address wallet) public view returns(Product[] memory) {
    Product [] memory newListProductByDealer = new Product[](countDealerProducts[wallet]);
    
    for(uint i = 0; i < countDealerProducts[wallet]; i++) {
        newListProductByDealer[i] = listOfDealerProduct[wallet][i];
    }
    
    return newListProductByDealer;
}
```